# Unable to find tbody in table without table id

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
URL = 'https://www.mohfw.gov.in/'
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find('table')
table_body = table.find_all('tbody')
print(table_body)
```

I want the tbody which is out of the comment. Every layer of tr and td have a span section and there are many layers of these.

[image]

Comment: The `tbody` in your image that appears to be outside the comment sign is not available in page source, so BeautifulSoup can't access that either. Try kicking out the comment sign and extracting the content out of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some content of tbody that you wish to grab from that page generate dynamically but you can find a link having json content if you look for it in dev tools. The data should all be there now

Try this:

```
import requests

URL = 'https://www.mohfw.gov.in/data/datanew.json'

page = requests.get(URL,headers={"x-requested-with":"XMLHttpRequest"})
for item in page.json():
    sno = item['sno']
    state_name = item['state_name']
    active = item['active']
    positive = item['positive']
    cured = item['cured']
    death = item['death']
    new_active = item['new_active']
    new_positive = item['new_positive']
    new_cured = item['new_cured']
    new_death = item['new_death']
    state_code = item['state_code']
    print(sno,state_name,active,positive,cured,death,new_active,new_positive,new_cured,new_death,state_code)
```

Output are like:

```
2 Andaman and Nicobar Islands 677 2945 2231 37 635 2985 2309 41 35
1 Andhra Pradesh 89932 371639 278247 3460 92208 382469 286720 3541 28
3 Arunachal Pradesh 899 3412 2508 5 987 3555 2563 5 12
4 Assam 19518 94592 74814 260 19535 96771 76962 274 18
5 Bihar 19716 124536 104301 519 19823 126714 106361 530 10
6 Chandigarh 1456 3209 1713 40 1539 3376 1796 41 04
```

Comment: I'm not looking to extract that data. I want the data present in tbody which is out of the comment section by default. If you scroll down a bit more you'll find the snippet I'm talking about. It's the exact same one in the image I posted in the question above.

Comment: Who told you I didn't find that? I told you it's not within page source. Perhaps you are referring to the portion that you see inspecting elements, as in using `Ctrl+Shift+I` but I'm suggesting to see using `Ctrl+U`. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks SIM. But that data isn't solving my purpose, hence the plea to extract the elements. SO if it's not within page source am I done? Should I look for another data source or there is a workaround. Appreciate your help!

Comment: You can try using selenium which will help you extract what you exactly see while inspecting elements. Check out the edit above and let me know if it still doesn't serve the purpose. Btw, what is it you wanna parse?

Comment: I want to parse all the data in the table present on the website, I'm working on a pet project that tweets out the new number of COVID cases in each state every day at a particular after the database is updated by the government on their website.

Comment: https://www.mohfw.gov.in/ the COVID statewide status shown here is something I want and the data we parsed has no relation to the data I see on the website. -Thanks

Comment: When I inspect the page I was able to see the data in tbody element but later as you told the data wasn't present when I inspect using Ctrl+U.

Comment: Check out the edit @mronevsall. You should find all the data now which are available in some json response populated dynamically by that site but you can track it using dev tools. Thanks.

Comment: this is brilliant. Exactly what I needed. -Thanks

Comment: Hello @SIM. I am having trouble segregating this data as inputting every type of data in different list. I want name of states in a list and sno in another and so on.

Comment: You should create a new post describing your new requirements @mronevsall. Someone might come along to solve that. Thanks.